# Raphael issue with drag and drop and translation

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am trying to get one of my components to sort of dock to the other one but something seems to get lost after the drag behaviour ends.
Go to the JSFiddle below, place the svg cursor somewhere closer to the top and click the component on the left. Now place the svg cursor a little further down and create another component. Now drag the bottom one onto the top one (from below, the code doesn't cater for from above yet) and drop it. It seems in the "up" drag handler my code as it currently stands applies the translation relative to where the component was created instead of relative to where it was dropped. I don't understand why :( Please help.

Open the console to see what I mean, I print some usefull info and object co-ordinates there.

Here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4rzul/trqrknqj/

And here is the entire drag function that is passed to the raphael svg object:

```
this.drag = function() {
            return {

                start:function () {
                    this.position = 0;
                    this.toFront();
                    this.lastdx ? this.odx += this.lastdx : this.odx = 0;
                    this.lastdy ? this.ody += this.lastdy : this.ody = 0;
                    this.animate({"fill-opacity": 0.5}, 500);
                    this.previousStroke = this.attr('stroke');
                }, 

                move:function (dx, dy) {
                    var draggedShape = this;
                    this.transform("t"+(dx+this.odx)+","+(dy+this.ody));
                    this.lastdx = dx;
                    this.lastdy = dy;
                },

                up: function(){
                    this.animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 500);
                    var target;
                    for(i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                        if(shapes[i] != this) {
                            target = shapes[i];
                            console.log("found");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("targetXY: " + target.getBBox().x + ", " + target.getBBox().y);
                    console.log("draggedXY: " + this.getBBox().x + ", " + this.getBBox().y);
                    var tX = target.getBBox().x - this.getBBox().x;
                    var tY = target.getBBox().y - this.getBBox().y;
                    console.log("translate XY to get from dragged to target: " + tX + ", " + tY);
                    this.transform("t"+(tX)+","+(tY));

                    console.log("but it moves relative to its original XY. Why??: " + this.getBBox().x + ", " +this.getBBox().y);
                }

         };
        }
```

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you just have one shape/path that you clone/translate rather than creating a different path with a different x,y each time ? Then when positioning the dragged one, you can just set it to have the exact same translation as the target + height of object ?

Comment: You mean clone the path in the "toolbox" pane? Ill try that, but have a feeling it is going to elicit the same behaviour as what I have now anyway. Could you perhaps give an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes, you don't really have to use the clone, it was just a way of pointing out why create different path objects with a different x,y each time, as you've already created one on the lhs. Here is an example that just uses the transform string for example http://jsfiddle.net/end6hfwh/4/

Comment: Great! Why does my approach not work though? I'm trying to understand Raphael and the svg transforms better so I can make better use of them. Are there perhaps non trivial tutorials out there that I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the original code, is that the objects dragged transform isn't taken into account when placing the final transform (on mouse up).

The simplest quick fix would probably be to do something like add 3 dots '...' to the transform, like

```
this.transform("...t"+(tX)+","+(tY +30));
```

This would mean translate taking into account previous transformation.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trqrknqj/1/) showing this running.

However, the general code feels like it could be simplified as well, like in the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/end6hfwh/4/).

The logic seems to be that the object is dragged, then both positions of objects calculated and dragged difference calculated. However, if you already know the object you want it to join, you know its transform, it doesn't actually matter where the dragged object is. It will always end up next to the target object, so no calculations really are needed. This may not quite be correct if this is just part of a larger problem where the original code needs to be in place.

I personally would stick to one path essentially cloned or identical (so all have the same starting x,y), however this is a bit of a personal taste thing, and depends on what other problems you may face later. It may be less optimal to have transforms, and flatten the transforms just into the path itself.

There's a few bits out there on transforms in general, which I would read up on first, and then once SVG transforms understood (if not already), then look towards Raphael transform strings.

The main Raphael transform string info can be found [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform)

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is a really good answer. Just to clarify, I have code that checks which objects are intersecting and decides which one to dock with so I do not know the target object upfront. Also it will sometimes be the dragged object as well as the target object(s) that need to be transformed to do the docking such as in the case where you want the dragged object to dock between two already docked objects. Thanks for the detailed answer.